# SQL max with condition

Tags: mysql

Any possibility of writing the below condition in Mysql query( sql script) format.

```
val =100    
max_val= select max(id) from tbl;    
dif =max_val - val    
if ( dif > 20)    
  max_val=val+20    
else if ( dif < 20)    
  max_val=select max(id) from tbl;
```

Comment: First of all, try to accept some answers on your other (14) questions, if you never accept an answer you will come across as a very ungrateful person. Secondly, what are you trying to achieve? It seems like something like this could be achieved using query conditions. Are those numbers (100 & 20) static or are they subject to change?

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

```
SELECT GREATEST(120,max(id)) from tbl;
```

#### Long answer:

What do you want to happen when `dif == 20`? You used `>` and `<` but never `==`?

Let's examine your code:

```
val =100    
max_val= select max(id) from tbl;    
dif =max_val - val
```

The first part is pretty obvious.

```
if ( dif > 20)
```

This actually means, `if max_val > 120`

```
  max_val=val+20
```

This comes down to `max_val = 120`

```
else if ( dif < 20)    
  max_val=select max(id) from tbl;
```

This `else if` doesn't even need to be there, because `max_val` already was the `max(id)` before. It does nothing.

So we can rewrite your pseudocode to

```
max_val= select max(id) from tbl;    
if ( max_val > 120)    
  max_val=120
```

So `max_val` can't be bigger than 120, so we can just select `GREATEST(120,max_val)`... or

```
SELECT GREATEST(120,max(id)) from tbl;
```

Comment: You actually need to use GREATEST, not MAX: `SELECT GREATEST(120,max(id)) from tbl;`

Answer (score 0):

Your else if - branch doesn't make much sense - you are just assigning the same value to max_val again.

For the first part, you could use the case statement (I tested this in Oracle, but according to the MySQL documentation, this should work in MySQL as well):

```
select maximum, difference, offset1, maximum + offset1 my_val from (
   select maximum, difference, 
   (case 
     when difference > 20 then 20
     else 0
    end  ) offset1 from (
     select max(id) maximum, max(id) - 100 difference from tbl) v1);
```

Kind regards, Frank